# Kafka Dependencies - ccs vs ce

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

To develop my Kafka connector I need to add a connect-API dependency.

Which one I should use?

For example mongodb connector [use](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka/blob/master/build.gradle.kts#L76) connect-api from [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/connect-api)

But links from [dev guide](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html) go to https://packages.confluent.io/maven/org/apache/kafka/connect-api/5.5.0-ccs/ and beside `5.5.0-ccs` there is also `5.5.0-ce` version.

So, at this moment last versions are:

- 2.5.0 from [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/connect-api)
- 5.5.0-ccs from [packages.confluent.io/maven](https://packages.confluent.io/maven/org/apache/kafka/connect-api/5.5.0-ccs/)
- 5.5.0-ce from [packages.confluent.io/maven](https://packages.confluent.io/maven/org/apache/kafka/connect-api/5.5.0-ce/)

What difference between all three variants?

Which one I should use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The 5.x version refer to Releases from Confluent whereas the 2.5.0 refers to the Open Source Apache Kafka project.

According to [this documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/available_packages.html#platform-packages) the `ce` belongs to the complete Confluent Platform, including all community and commercial component packages and the `ccs` to the Confluent Community component packages.

This doc on [licenses](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license-faq/) around Confluent/Kafka will give you more details.

According to Confluent documentation on [inter-compatibility](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html):

#### Confluent Platform and Apache Kafka Compatibility

```bash
Confluent Platform  Apache Kafka
7.6.x               3.6.x
7.1.x               3.1.x
7.0.x               3.0.x
6.2.x               2.8.x
6.1.x               2.7.x
6.0.x               2.6.x
5.5.x               2.5.x
5.4.x               2.4.x
5.3.x               2.3.x
...                 ...
```

Kafka-Connect is part of Open Source Apache Kafka and of both Confluent packages, so it would not matter which version to use. There is a difference when it comes to pre-build/supported connectors available in the confluent packages compared to Open source version. As you plan to build your own, it would not matter.

This blog post is a nice introduction to [Confluent Hub](https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-confluent-hub/).